# Android round image black

Tags: android, image, rounding, scale, stretch

I looked up to make images round. This worked but the image is not completely round...

[image: Round image]

What can i do so that the image take the full imageview. 
android:scaleType="fitXY" did not work.

This is the code to make the image round:

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int targetWidth = 150;
    int targetHeight = 150;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
            targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
            ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth),
                    ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
            Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
            new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                    sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
            new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
                    targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

When adding dividing by 2

[image]

My XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/round_image"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/round_image"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblEmail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/profiel_dark"
    android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblEmail"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```

Comment: I updated my answer you might take a look at

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: @ArmanP. This gives me the same problem.

Comment: Why Not applying your rounded Effect to The image itself and delete the other imagview.